# PHP lib for print save PDFs?

Tags: php, pdf, embedded-fonts, cmyk

I need to create print save PDFs with PHP, is there a library which supports embedded fonts and the CMYK color model?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.de/) is what you're looking for.

- embedding Fonts [can be a bit tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3530878/288773), but is possible
- for CMYk-support there's an [Addon](http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/44/)
- there are a lot of other [Addons](http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/) that may be useful